# Beginners tutorial on Jquery using Script#

Tags: jquery, script#

I'm trying to get on with Script# library and find it challenging to get some jQuery based Ajax code written. Is there any beginner's tutorial or important API documentation that can get me started real quick?

Comment: Are you already comfortable with jQuery?

Comment: @DuckMaestro: I'm not that comfortable with jQuery and think that C# style coding converted into jQuery would boost my productivity.

Comment: unless you have _very_ strict deadlines or only have a small piece of code to write with no maintenance, you will be better off learning jQuery instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently at MIX11, Nikhil Kothari, the creator of Script# delivered a very good session on Script# followed by a nice blog post covering how to use Script# with jQuery. This is perfect for the beginners. Below are the links for the video of the session and the followed blog post

video - http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/HTM16

archived blog post - http://web.archive.org/web/20110421060154/http://www.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp-MIX11.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Since you mentioned you're new to jQuery I would at least start with the jQuery documentation and get comfortable with the basics (see [jQuery Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)).

Once you are comfortable with jQuery, using it in Script# is fairly straight-forward because Script# already includes bindings for jQuery. To get started:

1. Make sure you're including jQuery in your HTML page or templates, as you would normally for jQuery (e.g. `<script src="[jQuery]"></script>`).
2. Verify your Script# project has a reference to `Script.jQuery(.dll)`.
3. Within your `.cs` source file(s) add `using jQueryApi;` (for convenience). This is the namespace containing Script#'s jQuery bindings.

Now you can utilize jQuery in your Script# code, in a fashion that maps fairly 1:1 to if you were using jQuery within JavaScript. The biggest difference though is in how you first create a jQuery object.

**In JavaScript:**

```
// selector
var paragraphs = $("p");    

// ad-hoc html
var someHtml = $("<strong>hello</strong>"); 

// existing DOM element
var elementFromDom = $(document.getElementById("myDiv"));

// ready callback
$(function() { doSomething(); });
```

**In Script#/C#:**

```
// selector
jQueryObject paragraphs = jQuery.Select("p");

// ad-hoc html
jQueryObject someHtml = jQuery.FromHtml("<strong>hello</strong>");

// existing DOM element
jQueryObject elementFromDom = jQuery.FromElement(Document.GetElementById("myDiv"));

// ready callback
jQuery.OnDocumentReady(delegate { DoSomething(); });
```